# Seaborn line plot confidence interval when using Median as the estimator

Tags: seaborn

How is the confidence interval calculated in a Seaborn line plot if I specify the estimator = np.median instead of the default mean? Is there a function in Python I can use to obtain the same results?

Comment: Seaborn use bootstrapping https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)

Comment: See also Kimberly Fessel's [instructive video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMRVEKf9jWA)